# How to avoid React props type errors in TypeScript when importing React classes defined in JavaScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We are in the process of converting a large React Javascript project to TypeScript.

We have existing files that define React classes:

```
// foo.js
class Foo extends React.Component { ... }

module.exports = Foo
```

And we would like to use these components in our new TypeScript files:

```
// bar.tsx
import Foo from "./foo"

export default class Bar extends React.Component<any, any> {
    render() { return <Foo baz="buzz" /> }
}
```

However this leads to the error:

`Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Foo> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Read...'.`

How can we avoid this error? We will be converting files to TypeScript whenever we modify them, but that's not a feasible strategy if we *also* have to modify any files included by the original file.

Answer (score 0):

We fixed this by adding a declaration file, `untyped-components.d.ts`. In this file we added a declaration for every untyped component:

```
declare module "foo" {
  const Foo: any
  export = Foo
}

...

declare module "zap" {
  const Zap: any
  export = Zap
}
```

And now whenever we convert a file we'll remove it from this file.